# 'Autocomplete' was not found in '@material-ui/core' with version ^4.11.2

Tags: material-ui

I Followed the lab version link for [Autocomplete](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js), according to warning it should be there in the core with version `4.11.2`, but it looks like it's still not available

Comment: `Autocomplete` is in the core in the v5 alpha (e.g. `v5.0.0-alpha.22`). It is in the lab for all v4 versions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import lab for Autocomplete component.

[autocomplete component documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)

To install lab you can use the following:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/lab

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/lab
```

[material ui lab](https://material-ui.com/components/about-the-lab/)

Comment: i can see the lab version is also importing the component from core also there is warning message which is suggesting to use component from core